# How to prove that $C_5\rtimes C_4$'s character table is only the character table of $C_5\rtimes C_4$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading Peter Webb's book on finite representation theory and after calculating the last row of the character table of a group, he mentions that it's the character table of $C_5\rtimes C_4$ and it is the only group that has this character table (it's an exercise to prove it).

I was thinking about how to prove it, but I can't even get started. I got a hint that I should think about Sylow subgroups. How does that connect to characters?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure how advanced the book in question is. For example, one can immediately read from just the degrees of the irreducible characters that the group has a normal abelian Sylow $5$-subgroup and a non-normal Sylow $2$-subgroup. One can then identify the Sylow $2$-subgroup as the derived subgroup (i.e. as the group of linear characters).

Comment: It's an introductory text. I have not yet heard about how it's done.

Comment: There are three possibilities for the group $C_5 \rtimes C_4$. Which one do you mean? To define a semidirect product you need to specify a homomorphism $\phi:C_4 \to {\rm Aut}(C_5)$.